# Glib convert epoch time to string

Tags: c, gtk, glib

I am using glibs functions to convert epoch time to string as follows.
But each time it is giving me some random time.

```
//Convert Time in string.
GDate *date = g_date_new_julian(timestampsecs);
gchar date_string[50];
g_date_strftime(date_string, 50, (const gchar*)"%a, %I:%M %p", (const GDate*)date);
printf("Date String [%s]\n", date_string );
```

Why this might be happening? am i missing anything?

Thanks,
PP.

**UPDATE:**

As said i tried with `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` following is the output,
It is the same as i was getting before using `setlocale`.

```
(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279703  computed dmy: 66 4293563716 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[1] [1272279703] --> [Tue, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279717  computed dmy: 80 4293563716 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[2] [1272279717] --> [Tue, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279720  computed dmy: 53 4293563717 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[3] [1272279720] --> [Fri, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279721  computed dmy: 54 4293563717 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[4] [1272279721] --> [Sat, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279721  computed dmy: 54 4293563717 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[5] [1272279721] --> [Sat, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279722  computed dmy: 55 4293563717 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[6] [1272279722] --> [Sun, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279723  computed dmy: 56 4293563717 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[7] [1272279723] --> [Mon, 12:00 AM]

(MyTestApp:7747): GLib-WARNING **:
OOPS julian: 1272279724  computed dmy: 57 4293563717 187
Date String Tik_INDEX[8] [1272279724] --> [Tue, 12:00 AM]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to call [setlocale()](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/setlocale.html) first, "LC_ALL" [should do it](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-running.html#setlocale). `POSIX` should also work, not sure about `C`.

[`g_date_strftime()`](http://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/glib/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html#g-date-strftime) is influenced by the locale setting. Its also good to store the result of `g_date_strftime()`, or anything else that fills a static buffer. You'll want to know how many bytes were actually printed to the buffer.

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
Please go-through updated part of the question.